# Is it possible to write an application that plays music in the background on iOS using Adobe Packager for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, flash, adobe, air

I would like my application to be able to remain running while the user goes and uses another application. (It will be playing music) Additionally, does anyone know about how to communicate w/ Cocoa Touch from this environment?

If you think this is not possible, which platforms are capable of this (other than the obj-c mac x-code route, which I am trying to avoid)?

Edit:

After a week, no answers at all. Very disappointing. I don't normally ask questions - this is my first! Isn't there anyone from Adobe here?

Comment: Probably not. This is why developing native is always going to give you more flexibility. Good luck though, I'm sure that someone can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having seen a project that I wrote being ported by someone else to work on iOS, using the iOS packager, I can say that it's totally possible that sounds playing in the AIR app can play even after you "close" the application whether you intend them to or not (continued playing in this case was not the desired situation).  As long as the application exists somewhere, playing sounds appear not to stop without an explicit command otherwise.